# Eclipse Maven Clean Install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to clean install by pointing to my local maven using neon eclipse external tool configuration. I get the below error when i try to run the program. I'm using mac. I installed eclipse maven plugin but i still get this error. Can somebody please point me in the right direction.

/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn.bat: line 1: @REM: command not found
/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn.bat: line 2:`@REM Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one

Comment: .bat on a mac ? I'm not mac pro but is it possible ?

Comment: Just add the `bin` folder to PATH and run `mvn`, it should sort things out automatically.

Comment: Thanks you @Pascal Heraud and Jorn Vernee..Yes is a .bat file. I have configured the eclipse external tool configuration setting as below: Location: apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn.bat. But my maven on the terminal works fine when i do mvn -version. its only when i try to run using eclipse its giving that error.

Comment: i'm a windows guy so i don't know how to use mac yet, getting used to it. i want to know something is mvn.bat for windows and mvn for mac? Since the bin folder shows both mvn.bat and mvn.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you installed the Maven plugin, you should configure it to use your external Maven installation rather than the Embedded version.

`Preferences -> Maven -> Installations`. Click `Add...` Use `Directory...` to select Maven's installation folder, and click `Finish`. Make sure that your custom installation is checked in the Installations list. This will allow you to use Eclipse's Maven features rather than running Maven bare as an external tool.

For example, selecting `Run As -> Maven build...` from a project's context menu.